# Why is unity OnApplicationPause called twice on android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, duplicates, onresume, onpause

I have a simple game object (the main UI object) with `OnApplicationPause` that prints out the `Pause` status `(true/false)` in the debug log.
When I `run` it on android, and press the Home `Button` to leave the app, I see that the `OnApplicationPause()` is called `twice` in a row, with the same `pauseStatus` (true). The same happens when I reopen the app: the `OnApplicationPause` is called twice with `Pause` status false.

Why is it being called twice and can I avoid it? Am I doing anything wrong?

I also tried to create a separate GameObject, that includes the same debug code. The issue doesn't occur there - only in my main UI object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that your script containing the `OnApplicationPause()` method is not present twice in the Scene when Pause occurs? or present on a previous Scene on a `DontDestroyOnLoad` GameObject?

[OnApplicationPause](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) is called on each active `MonoBehaviour` when pause occurs.

So having two `Debug.Log` means two scripts instances running if you don't call it manually yourself.

Comment: you are correct with that lead: the script was associated to 2 different objects in the scene (not sure why though, the code was coming from a 3rd party unity package, which included this demo scene, objects, script, etc). thanks!